# I don't like how "yaml.dump()" saves its files. Is there an alternative?

Tags: python, save, yaml

I've discovered YAML recently and it has turned out to be a fantastic format for my project (I'm creating a text-based RPG). It's handling everything I need flawlessly - area files (rooms with descs, exits, objs, npcs, etc), script files, npc files, object files... it tackles them all! There's just one thing...

When updating values in these files I of course need to write them back to disk to keep the changes. Unfortunately YAML's `dump()` method really makes a mess of things. First it alphabetizes all the keys, and then it appears to put one k:v pair per line. This effectively took a file with 5 lines and turned it into 94 lines.

I've tried writing the YAML objects back to disk using `write()` but it throws

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

at me. Pickle would save it, but I think that would destroy the YAML-ness of the data. Is there a good way to save a YAML object without `dump()`? I've heard mention of SQLite, would that work the same as YAML? I have little to no database experience but it seems like YAML objects are basically databases. Would it be worth re-coding everything to use SQLite? Is it easy to save changed values with it, unlike the problem I have having now?

Any assistance here would be great. I love YAML a lot. I struggled for a long time trying to find a way to store all the data I need for my game and when I found YAML it was as if it glowed with holy light as a chorus of angels sang their glory upon it - so you can understand if I'd first like to know of a way to save YAML data to disk without using `dump()`. If not, suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is a way of serialising and deserialising dictionaries and lists between Python and a text-editable format.  It isn't suited for storing rich data, multi-user access, fast lookups of data, guaranteeing data integrity and all the other things that make a database a database.

You're using YAML as a database, but it's not a database.  For example, the reordering of the keys is an artefact of the fact that `key: value` pairs are represented as a Python dictionary, which is inherently unordered.

You definitely need to spend some time learning a bit about databases.

SQLite is as good a place to start as any.  You could also look at Postgres or MySQL.  You'll probably want to read some beginner's guides to SQL and to doing database access with Python.  There are plenty on the web.

Comment: However, this is not the question. YAML work great for storing data in a human-readable format. And once you loaded it, you have native Python data structures and hence faster access than any database can realistically provide, at the cost of memory. DBs win when the data can't be in memory at one time, yes.

Comment: I checked out a couple of vids talking about SQLite in Python and it looks like there would be a lot to learn going that route. The only problem I have with that is that it might halt my progress for a bit. However, it appears that maybe it may be more powerful than simply accessing a 2d dictionary object. How much slower would a database be compared to YAML? If say I had an area mapped out in a database where each row holds all the data needed for 1 room in the area and there is 50 rooms, would it really be all that slow?

Comment: A database should typically be faster than YAML, since there would be less string processing involved (but it depends on how well you design the DB structure)

Comment: @drew, Re. speed, as delnan says, once the YAML is parsed, it's all in memory, which is super-fast.  If you just have 50 rooms, then no doubt it is reasonable to hold it all in memory at once.  If you don't want to learn about databases yet, and YAML isn't working for you, then why not represent your rooms as objects and persist them to disk as pickles?  You could write an import script that takes room definitions from text files, YAML files or CSV files and then creates objects from these, and pickles them on a save operation.

Comment: That sounds good, though I am still a bit wet behind the ears when it comes to OOP. That said, I do want to be able to incorporate OOP as much as possible. I sort of feel like it'd be irresponsible not to... though I'm not sure whether or not that's a good mindset to have about it. I think I have an understanding of what you're suggesting with representing rooms as objects though, and will give that a shot. Ultimately my issue with how the files are saved may have to be solved by creating an editor instead of editing the files directly - that was the problem I had (and will have with Pickle).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to preserve order with YAML and Python.

Python has OrderedDict and YAML has an equivalent ordered mapping called [omap](http://yaml.org/type/omap.html).

Unfortunately when you dump an OrderedDict with YAML it tries to preserve the OrderedDict python object type instead of converting it to YAML omap.  This is in part because the YAML specification is meant to play nice with a plethora of languages, and technically a YAML map or omap allow duplicate keys I believe (I'd have to re-research that, but I've seen it cited as a 'key' difference between YAML and JSON -- YAML declares how it handles duplicate keys where JSON doesn't.)

Anyways, there is a way to tell YAML to load data into an OrderedDict and to dump the OrderedDict sequencially into a map or omap.  The most concise source I have found is [py-lessly](https://github.com/dsc/py-lessly/blob/master/lessly/data/yaml_omap.py).  Though there are some other implementations around the web.  I also like that the py-lessly code dumps to a simple yaml map which doesn't require !!omap next to every dictionary - keeps the YAML pretty!

There is also [layered-yaml-attrdict-config](https://github.com/mk-fg/layered-yaml-attrdict-config) which loads YAML data into an OrderedDict subclass called AttrDict with some additional features.  I had to add some stuff to this implementation to work for me - I think it lost the order when dumping, so I added code from the py-lessly implementation.  I also wanted to work with combined dict and list structure and had to write some extra code to apply AttrDict to the whole data structure recursively.

From those examples you can see how to use YAML to work with ordered mappings.  I'm currently working on implementing this for application settings which I would like to stay relatively human-readable and for which order is important.